# Sum columns of one dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I have two dataframes that look like those:

```
df1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
        "Year": [2001, 2003, 2003, 2004]
    }
)

df2 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
        "2001": [111, 112, 113, 114],
        "2002": [221, 222, 223, 224],
        "2003": [331, 332, 333, 334],
        "2004": [441, 442, 443, 444]
    }
)
```

I'd like to sum each year column of the second df (df2), taking in account only names whose corresponding year in df1 is the same year or later. Desired output:

```
┌──────┬──────┐
│ Year ┆  Sum │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 2001 ┆  111 │  
│ 2002 ┆  221 │
│ 2003 ┆  996 │  (= 331 + 332 + 333)
│ 2004 ┆ 1770 │  (= 441 + 442 + 443 + 444)
└──────┴──────┘
```

I'm new to Polars (coming from Pandas), and I'm not sure how to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html#polars.DataFrame.melt) `df2` to put it in a form more "compatible" with `df1`. It "unpivots" the specified column headers into rows. `Year` should be cast into an `int` column at this point from `str`:

```py
df2.melt(id_vars='Name', variable_name='Year').with_columns(
    pl.col('Year').cast(pl.Int64)
)

shape: (16, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ Name ┆ Year ┆ value │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ i64  ┆ i64   │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ A    ┆ 2001 ┆ 111   │
│ B    ┆ 2001 ┆ 112   │
│ C    ┆ 2001 ┆ 113   │
│ D    ┆ 2001 ┆ 114   │
│ A    ┆ 2002 ┆ 221   │
│ B    ┆ 2002 ┆ 222   │
│ C    ┆ 2002 ┆ 223   │
│ D    ┆ 2002 ┆ 224   │
│ A    ┆ 2003 ┆ 331   │
│ B    ┆ 2003 ┆ 332   │
│ C    ┆ 2003 ┆ 333   │
│ D    ┆ 2003 ┆ 334   │
│ A    ┆ 2004 ┆ 441   │
│ B    ┆ 2004 ┆ 442   │
│ C    ┆ 2004 ┆ 443   │
│ D    ┆ 2004 ┆ 444   │
└──────┴──────┴───────┘
```

You can then `join` this with `df1` on the `Name`, and filter the resulting rows by the year condition you specified:

```py
(...).join(df1, on='Name').filter(pl.col('Year') >= pl.col('Year_right'))
```

From there it's a simple `groupby` and `agg`regation on the `Year`. All together:

```py
df2.melt(id_vars='Name', variable_name='Year').with_columns(
    pl.col('Year').cast(pl.Int64)
).join(df1, on='Name').filter(pl.col('Year') >= pl.col('Year_right')).groupby(
    'Year', maintain_order=True
).agg(
    Sum=pl.col('value').sum()
)
```

```py
shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ Year ┆ Sum  │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 2001 ┆ 111  │
│ 2002 ┆ 221  │
│ 2003 ┆ 996  │
│ 2004 ┆ 1770 │
└──────┴──────┘
```

(`maintain_order` is optional but slower, can achieve the same effect with a `.sort('Year')` after the `agg` if truly desired.)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
df2 = df2.join(df1, on='Name')

out = {}
for c in df2.select(pl.col('^\d+$')):
    m = int(c.name) >= df2['Year']
    out[c.name] = c.filter(m).sum()

out = pl.DataFrame(out)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
shape: (1, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ 2001 ┆ 2002 ┆ 2003 ┆ 2004 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 111  ┆ 221  ┆ 996  ┆ 1770 │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

---

Or transposed output:

```py
out = out.transpose(
    include_header=True, header_name="Year", column_names=["Sum"]
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ Year ┆ Sum  │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 2001 ┆ 111  │
│ 2002 ┆ 221  │
│ 2003 ┆ 996  │
│ 2004 ┆ 1770 │
└──────┴──────┘
```